# What should be the location for keeping the html template files for using ngRoute in AngulatJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute, route-provider

I am trying to setup a new angularJS projects using ngRoute and facing difficulties in resolving the absolute path for keeping my template html files.

Below is my project structure:

```
webapp
- css
- js
   - controller
     - controller.js
   - service
     - service.js
   - app.js
- template
  - template1.html
  - template2.html
```

below is my routeProvider config:

```
myCacheApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/CacheInfo',{template:'This is the computers Route'})
        .when('/CacheRefresh',{templateUrl: '../template/template1.html'});
}]);
```

I have given relative path for the template1.html from app.js

But the template is not getting loaded, when trying to access the /CacheRefresh URL, nothing is happening.

Am I doing something wrong? How to specify the path of the template html file while using ngRoute?

Please help.

Comment: With the current layout you have Angular is going to load templates based on the relative URL in the browser - it does not load templates based on the file system. I'd recommend using a module bundler or using urls relative to the base path of your website, i.e, if `template` is located in your root directory on your website, you'd want `/template/template1.html` as your `templateUrl`, not `../....`

Comment: Even after I set like `/template/template1.html` in `templateUrl`, It is not working.
`.when('/CacheRefresh',{templateUrl: '/template/template1.html'});`

Comment: try js/template/template1.html

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to refer the template1.html using the below path:

```
.when('/CacheRefresh',{templateUrl: 'template/template1.html'});
```